# This about a chat application made using firestore and I can't scroll ths widget

Tags: flutter

This about  a chat application made using firestore and I cant scroll this widget , when the screen is filled it just stop showing the new items, like its going user the screen,it is  basically the chat feature of the app , a chat should scroll,there aren't any syntax errors, I ma new to flutter, please help

```
    class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      String chatRoomId;
      @override
      ChatScreen(this.chatRoomId);

      _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
    }

    class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
      DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
      TextEditingController messageController = new 
    TextEditingController();

      Stream chatmessageStream;

      Widget chatMessageList() {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: chatmessageStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount:
                      snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return MessageTile(
                        snapshot.data.documents[index].get("message"),
                        snapshot.data.documents[index].get("sendBy") ==
                            Constants.myName);
                  })
              : Container(width: 100, height: 100, child: Text(''));
        });
  }

      sendMessage() {
    if (messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = {
        "message": messageController.text,
        "sendBy": Constants.myName,
        "time": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      };
      databaseMethods.addConversationMessages(widget.chatRoomId, messageMap);
      messageController.text = "";
    }
  }


     void initState() {
  
  
 databaseMethods.getConversationMessages(widget.chatRoomId)
.then((value) {
      setState(() {
        chatmessageStream = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: User(widget.chatRoomId
            .toString()
            .replaceAll("_", "")
            .replaceAll(Constants.myName, "")),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            chatMessageList(),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0xff1F1F1F),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
                        child: TextField(
                          cursorColor: Colors.redAccent,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                          controller: messageController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                              ),
                              hintText: "Type a message ",
                              // filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[800],
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        sendMessage();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [Colors.red[400], Colors.red[400]])),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/send.jpeg",
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;
  User(this.userName);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            userName,
            style: textFieldTextStyle(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool isSendByMe;
  MessageTile(this.message, this.isSendByMe);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(left: isSendByMe ? 0 : 4, right: isSendByMe ? 14 : 0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      alignment: isSendByMe ? Alignment.centerRight : 
    Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: isSendByMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(23),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(23),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(23),
                  )
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(23),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(23),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(23),
                  ),
            color: isSendByMe ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey[850]),
        child: Text(
          message,
          style: textFieldTextStyle(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please through the code.

Comment: See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html. Don't you need a ScrollController?

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics just remove this,
set your container width height for blank condition.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child:Stack( children: [
                 chatMessageList(), 
                 Container(..............),
               ], 
           ),
         ),



return StreamBuilder(
    stream: chatmessageStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
             physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount:
                  snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return MessageTile(
                    snapshot.data.documents[index].get("message"),
                    snapshot.data.documents[index].get("sendBy") ==
                        Constants.myName);
              })
          : Container(
            width: 100,
           height: 100,
           child: Text('')
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: can you show your ''MessageTile'' code also.to get your issue proper

Comment: check again my answer,this issue may be for container width height not set.

Comment: Tried it , still the same , the list is being rendered in stack , could it be the problem?

Comment: Stack(
          children: [
            chatMessageList(),
            Container(..............),
              
          ],
        ),

Comment: check again, if you use stack then use singlechildrenscrollView and set to never scroll to listview.

Comment: No change yet, when the stack is replaced with a column , its scrolling nicely ,but  I need it be a stack to preserve the alignment and to make the text input rise above with the keyboard.